# Webpack - Typescript aliases error in production mode only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having a problem with a React project configured with Webpack and using Typescript. Containerized with Docker (CI/CD with gitlab) .

Before we didn't use aliases on our project and builds in production environment worked without any problem.

Since then, we've switched to using aliases with this configuration :

In webpack.common.js :

```
 alias: {
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname,  'src/assets'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      Api: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api'),
      Types: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@types'),
      Helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers'),
      Config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/config'),
      Store: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/store'),
},
...,
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
            options: {
              getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                before: [isDevelopment && ReactRefreshTypeScript()].filter(Boolean),
              }),
              transpileOnly: isDevelopment,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

And my configuration tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "pretty":true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" :true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017", "esnext"],
    "typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "Assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "Components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "Api/*": ["src/api/*"],
      "Types/*": ["src/@types/*"],
      "Helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
      "Config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "Store/*": ["src/store/*"],
    } 
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/index.tsx",
    "./src/**/*",
  ],
  "files": ["./src/@types/custom.d.ts"],
  "exclude":["/node_modules"],
}
```

I add that in dev everything works, and a npm run build locally manages to build the project, but when it passes via the CI/CD chain on gitlab and build image returns me this kind of errors :

```
#16 13.97 ERROR in ./src/routes/Pages/Users.tsx:10:22
#16 13.97 TS2307: Cannot find module 'Types/resources/users' or its corresponding type declarations.
#16 13.97      8 | import { UserState } from "Store/user/reducer"
#16 13.97      9 | import { ServerSideTable } from "@optalp/react-server-side-table"
#16 13.97   > 10 | import { User } from "Types/resources/users"
#16 13.97        |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And a part of my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^22.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "polished": "^4.2.2",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --mode-development --hot",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env NODE_ENV=production",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-refresh-typescript": "^2.0.9",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.5",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
    "ts-loader": "^8.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.10.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any clues? A wrong tsconfig.json or webpack configuration ?
If there's a need for more configuration, I can specify it further.

Thank you !

Comment: What's inside `Types` (`src/@types/*`) alias folder? Are those `*.d.ts` files?

Comment: @BogdanGishka yes exactly

Comment: In this case my answer below should help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the way how you import types. During production build all types are ignored, which means the import below won't work:

```
import { User } from "Types/resources/users"
```

Which is why all types have to imported [using `type` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export):

```
import type { User } from "Types/resources/users"
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm afraid it won't make much difference, I've put the example with the "Types" alias, but all the aliases i've set up will show the problem, not just this folder here